# Как решить проблему с высотой Datepicker'a?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

Есть такой код:

```
$('#cnp_0').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',

            maxDate: "+180",
            firstDay: 1,
            defaultDate: '01.01.1982',
            constraintInput: true,
            yearRange: "-84:+0",
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            minDate: 'yy' - 70,
            onSelect: function (date) {
                calculateDate(date, $('#cnp_0'));
            },
            onClose:function(evt, ui){
                check.call(this, dateReg);
            }
        });
```

Под Windows все хорошо в каждом из браузеров 
Под Mac в Chrome и Safari мне выводит все возможные опции выбора лет во всю высоту браузера. В Firefox такого не наблюдается. Если убиваю yearRange - все работает хорошо, но тогда я могу выбрать года в определенной области (если выбрал 1982 год, то могу выбрать между 1972 до 1992)
Помогите решить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать точную нижнюю границу

```
$('#cnp_0').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    maxDate: "+180",
    firstDay: 1,
    defaultDate: '01.01.1982',
    constraintInput: true,
    yearRange: "1946:+0",
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: 'yy' - 70,
    onSelect: function (date) {
        calculateDate(date, $('#cnp_0'));
    },
    onClose:function(evt, ui){
        check.call(this, dateReg);
    }
});
```

Так же у вас изначально `minDate` выше чем нижняя граница выбора.

Comment: Попробую, спасибо

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Все так колбаса во всю высоту браузера